# How to reflect setting change on listview from another class

Tags: android, android-listview

I have custom Listview  in which I am showing events name and In setting option I want to change events font type.

notifyDataSetChanged is not working and I doesn't want to use recreate() method of activity.

Comment: Create one Setting class or preference that store all your settings and your activity onResume make necessary changes according settings

Comment: that is what I am asking how can I reflect those changes on listview

Comment: call notifyDataSetChanged on activity resume

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged is not working